# How many times onUpdate function will trigger on batch update?

Tags: android, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

I want to update two fields in a document in a collection called `recipes` and i used the batch update to do it:

```
let recipeRef = db.collection('recipes').doc(`${recipeId}`);
let batch = db.batch();
batch.update(recipeRef, {ratingsCount : admin.firestore.FieldValue.increment(1)});
batch.update(recipeRef, {totalRating : admin.firestore.FieldValue.increment(snap.data().rating)})
return batch.commit();
```

And I have a trigger function on the `recipes` collection like this:

```
exports.RecipeUpdated = functions.firestore
.document('recipes/{recipeId}')
.onUpdate((change, context) => 
{
    //code
});
```

My question is as there are two updates in the above batch, will this also trigger the `onUpdate` function twice Or since the batch writes completes atomically, trigger will be called only ones? I want the trigger to be called only one time.

Comment: This seems like something that should be easy to observe if you just run the code.

Comment: I did and `onUpdate` only called one time.

Comment: Maybe a trivial question (or I miss something): why do you need to use two updates and do not use only one?? `batch.update(recipeRef, {ratingsCount : admin.firestore.FieldValue.increment(1), totalRating : admin.firestore.FieldValue.increment(snap.data().rating)})`

Comment: @RenaudTarnec oh.. i didnt know i could do that..

Comment: Actually it is what Alex explains in his answer. Sorry @Alexmamo I didn't read you answer carefully before writing my comment....;-)

Comment: @RenaudTarnec No problem Renaud, it's actually the same thing.

Comment: K.. thank u very much all of you..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As @DougStevenson mentioned in his comment, you should just simply run the code and see the behaviour. But note, even if you are using the same `recipeRef`, you are creating two difference updates in your batch. In this case, the result that you'll get will be that `onUpdate()` will fire twice.

If you want to be called only once, then you should **not** create two different updates, you can create a single one. [update()](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/add-data#update_fields_in_nested_objects) function allows you to pass multiple properties that can be updated. If you are using objects, than  simply get a reference to the document, get it, make the changes and write it back.

Comment: Thank u very much for ur answer. I didnt know that multiple fields can be updated with a single query. Also, I did run this code after posting this question, and **it only called one time** even though u mentioned that it will be called twice. I didnt know that was supposed to happen. Thats why I waited for someone to answer.

Comment: Yes you can update multiple properties in a single document at once. Seeing only the code in your question, I cannot tell you the reason why it was called only once but for sure when you perfom two separate updates, even if are done in batch, the `onUpdate()` function will fire twice.